# Difference between Child and Descendant Combinator Selectors

Tags: css, css-selectors, selector

I've been trying to practice using the child combinator selector and seem to be having some mixed results.

I set up the following sample html:

```
<div class="One">
    One Text
    <div class="Two">
        Two Text
        <div class="Three">
            Three Text
            <div class="Four">
                 THE BASE IS HERE.  
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then I tried to do the following.

```
div.One > div.Two {
    color: blue;
}
```

My results were the same as if I had just used a descendant selector.  Although, when I tried using the child combinator with ordered list inside of a unordered list, it seemed to work just as I would expect.

What's going on here?

Below is an example of how I would expect it to behave.

Sample HTML:

```
<ul class="Parent">
<li>One</li>
<li>Two</li>
    <ol class="Child">
        <li>One One</li>
        <li>Two Two</li>
    </ol>
<li>Three</li>
```

and using this selector:

```
ul.Parent > li {
color: blue;
}
```

This second example ONLY selects the child as I would expect it to behave.  But when using the nested divs... it goes always down the chain to the grand children.

So my question is, why does it only select the child in the second example and not in the first?

Comment: I'm not clear on your question. What happening (or not happening) that you're expecting? And BTW, `color` is an inherited property, so even if you limit it to the `.Two` div, all of its children will also get it.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp has some notes on the differences. Look at 'Descendant' and 'Child' for the answer here.

Comment: umm, a child is a descendant, right?

Comment: @torazaburo a child is a descendant, but a descendant is not necessarily a child.  I think that's where the confusion is in this question.

Comment: Child is a subset of descendant. For example, Two, Three and Four are descendants of One but only Two is a child of One. Consider your family tree where your great-grandmother had your grandmother as a child and a descendant but also you and your mother are descendants but not considered children of hers.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/QnzkG/5/  is what is happening.  What I would expect to happen would be something more like http://jsfiddle.net/vf43raxu/

I only want the child and not the grand-child div, in this case meaning class three and four divs.

Comment: So what I mean to say is that my code seems to not be using the ">" child combinator selector at all.  Except in the case when I use it with an ordered list.

Comment: Instead of using `color: blue` for testing selectors, use (for example) `border: 1px solid black`. `border`, unlike `color`, is not an inheritable property and will cause less confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first example, there is only one `.One` element and only one `.Two` element, and that `.Two` is a child of that `.One`. So whether you use the child or descendant combinator isn't going to make any difference — both selectors are going to match just that lone `.Two` element. Any `E > F` pair is necessarily also an `E F` pair; the former is a proper subset of the latter.

Your second example is flawed for two reasons:

- If you want to compare the child and descendant combinators, avoid using `color` — as others have mentioned it's inherited which can confuse you. (This applies to both examples.)
- The only reason it's not actually being inherited by the inner `ol` is because you're not correctly nesting it within one of the outer `li` elements.

However, it nevertheless demonstrates why the child combinator works as advertised: because the inner `li` elements are not children of the outer `ul`. They are children of the inner `ol`.

Answer (score 4):

The child combinator selector (`>`) targets an element that is a *child* of its parent. It does not target descendants beyond the children.

The descendant selector targets the child *and other descendants* of the parent/ancestor.

Both selectors target child-level elements, so in those cases there won't appear to be any difference between them.

See a list of selectors with definitions here: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors

Answer (score 0):

Child combinator = only apply css to all immediate child.
Descendant combinator = apply css to all nested child

```css
#container__descendant  .box {
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    background-color: skyblue;
    border: 1px solid red;
}


#container__child > .box {
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    background-color: lightgreen;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<h5>Descendant Combinator</h5>
<div id="container__descendant">
    <div class="box">Immediate .BOX</div>
    <div class="box-2">Immediate .BOX-2</div>
  <div>
    <div class="box">Nested .BOX</div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr />
<h5>Child Combinator</h5>
<div id="container__child">
    <div class="box">Immediate .BOX</div>
    <div class="box-2">Immediate .BOX-2</div>
  <div>
    <div class="box">Nested .BOX</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">Immediate .BOX</div>
</div>
<div class=”box”>Nearby .BOX</div>
</body>
</html>
```