# How to extract anchor elements nested in multiple division elements

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, css-selectors

I am trying to extract anchor elements from my beautiful soup object with a common class attr each nested in multiple divisions. The divisions are repeated and separated with some scripts

I have tried to take advantage of the common class attrs in the anchor elements to extract them

The code I got:

```
<div id='container'>
<div class='nested'>
<a href='some url' class='link'>
</a>
</div>
</div>

#some scripts ....

<div id='container'>
<div class='nested'>
<a href='some url' class='link'>
</a>
</div>
</div>
```

What I tried:

```
import requests, bs4, webbrowser

webpage=requests.get('some url')
webpage.raise_for_status()
soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(webpage.text)
links=soup.select('.link a')

for i in range(0,5):
  webrowser.open('intial site url'+links[i].get('href'))
print(links)
```

No tabs were opened.Print links gave a blank list

Comment: I am new to this site and i hope u like the format ;). Have been working on format skills for a while XD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your line code:

```
links=soup.select('.link a')
```

To

```
  links=soup.find_all('a',{'class':'link'})
  print(links)
```

O/P:

```
[<a class="link" href="some url">
</a>, <a class="link" href="some url">
</a>]
```

To Get href form `a` tag:

```
for link in links:
  href = link['href']
  print(href)
```

Comment: but they are nested within divisions would that work?

Comment: @JadAH `find_all()` method return list of `a` tag which has `link` class

Comment: i used the print(links) and it did give me a full list of these anchor elements butt my webbrowser function doesnt seem to open them up

Comment: that is correct i got such an output from print(links) but my last line of code is supposed to get the href out of these anchor elements and open up corrseponding tabs but my webbrowser.open function is opening up tabs to my intial url typed in

Comment: for i in range(0,5):
   webbrowser.open(links[i].get('href'))

Comment: when i wrote (print links[i]) it suprisingly gave the full url  of the intial site and destination of the links

Answer (score 0):

`.link a` will do all child `a` tags with parents having class `link`. The space between is actually a [css descendant combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator) which means the lhs is parent and rhs is child. Remove the space to apply to same element. Notice that you need to extract the href attribute from the matched tags.

```
links = [item['href'] for item in soup.select('a.link')]
```

If you need to specify the parent div by class then it is

```
.nested a.link
```

or more simply

```
.nested .link
```

Comment: Thanks for expanding my horizons XD

Comment: does div.nested>a.link do the same?

Comment: Of course its easier to use yours but clarifying this would be real helpful.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33442967/difference-between-child-and-descendant-combinator-selectors

Comment: This site is the best XD sorry for the nuisance i shouldve searched in the posted questions